# Delaying execution of a line of code upon an event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this code, I am trying to re-spawn players in different group in different locations. Although the code teleports the player successfully to the desired location, milisencond later the player is teleported to the default re-spawn location.

Right now, this works fine.

Are there any ways of delaying the execution of `player.Teleport()` so the player can teleport after the game teleports the player to the default location?

Trying `Thread.Sleep` just delays both of the teleportaion process.

```
public void OnPlayerRespawn(UnturnedPlayer player, Vector3 position, byte angle)
{
    player.Teleport(HQLocation1);
}
```

Comment: You should try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ they might have better answers

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Mfusiki, my first time being around here! Going to do that right now.

Comment: What calls `OnPlayerRespawn`?

Comment: An event that the game detects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this if this can be done without parameters:

```
public void OnPlayerRespawn(UnturnedPlayer player, Vector3 position, byte angle)
{    
    Invoke("TeleportPlayer", 5);
}

private void TeleportPlayer()
{
    player.Teleport(HQLocation1);
}
```

If you need parameters you can use a coroutine:

```
public void OnPlayerRespawn(UnturnedPlayer player, Vector3 position, byte angle)
{    
    StartCoroutine(TeleportPlayer(some parameters));
}

private IEnumerator TeleportPlayer(some parameters)
{
    // wait before doing other stuff
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

    player.Teleport(HQLocation1);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, parameters are a must too! Thank you for your reply, and have tried your coroutine method, but gives me back some errors. `TeleportPlayer(UnturnedPlayer) must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial` and yield return new gives me `Invalid token "return" in class, struct or interface member declaration` any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, it now works! Thank you so much for your help, it means a lot to me! <3

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any ways of delaying the execution of "player.Teleport" so
>   the player can teleport after the game teleports the player to the
>   default location?

Yes, use the [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) function. The first parameter is the function to call and the second one is how much time you want it to wait before calling the function. This can also be done with a `Coroutine` but `Invoke` is more appropriate for this simple task.

```
public void OnPlayerRespawn(UnturnedPlayer player, Vector3 position, byte angle)
{
    Invoke("Teleport", 2);
}

void Teleport(){
    player.Teleport(HQLocation1);
}
```